# Docker Swarm - database connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-swarm, springboot

I am running a Spring Boot application with Docker Swarm and I use Postgres for database.

When I run both of them as Docker service, database connection fails consistently and randomly (as you can see on the timestamp) as the log says:

> 2017-10-26T**17:14:15**.200415747Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a |
>   LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
>
> 2017-10-26T**17:43:36**.481718562Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a |
>   LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
>
> 2017-10-26T**17:43:56**.954152654Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a |
>   LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
>
> 2017-10-26T**17:44:17**.434171472Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a |
>   LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
>
> 2017-10-26T**17:49:04**.154174253Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a |
>   LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

I couldn't understand or discover the reason for this. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Edit:

We realized that, when testing the application, it also throws an error like this:

> SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not
>   available, request timed out after 937517ms

Thanks.

Comment: I get same error using Python on a Postgres database using swarm.

Comment: Same issue.  Client is Java.  This is causing serious stability issues for our apps.